# What is Ursua holding tightly?

Tags: aguirre-wrath-of-god

After being shot, and lying down next to his wife Ines, Ursua holds something very tightly in his hand, refusing to give it to Aguirre's crew.

It is mentioned several times, and we can see him holding something in his right hand, and the crew also wants to know what it is.

For example, here at [31:41](https://youtu.be/5ptjYvCVq3w?t=1901):

[image: Ursua]

After his execution, I don't remember it being mentioned again.

Has it ever known, maybe based on real events, what he was holding?